# view of query in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a collection ,this is one of it's docs :

```
{
"_id" : 1 ,
"first_name" : "john",
"phone" : [ 
    {
        "type" : "mobile",
        "number" : "9151112233"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "home",
        "city_code" : 51,
        "number" : "55251544"
    }, 
    {
        "type" : "mobile",
        "number" : "9152425125"
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm searching for "phones" that contain type "mobile" and show them.

I need something like this :

```
{
 "number" : "9151112233",
 "number" : "9152425125"
}
```

I write this query for that :

```
db.main.find({ _id : 1 , 'phone.type' : "mobile" },{'phone.number' : true , _id : false}).forEach(printjson)
```

I want to show only numbers that their types are mobile but this query show all to numbers because this single doc contain others too.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the aggregation framework along with the $unwind, $match and $project commands. This:

```
db.main.aggregate({$unwind:"$phone"},{$match:{"phone.type":"mobile"}},{$project:{"phone.number":1,"_id":0}})
```

produces this output:

```
{ "phone" : { "number" : "9151112233" } }
{ "phone" : { "number" : "9152425125" } }
```

which only matches the mobile numbers.

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/